# Is the Java NIOServer from the Rox Tutorial actually safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

The [Rox Java NIO Tutorial](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) has an example NIO Server class.  I'm not convinced that the code is actually thread-safe.  The below code is called by some user class to send data through the server:

```
public void send(SocketChannel socket, byte[] data) {
    synchronized (this.pendingChanges) {
        this.pendingChanges.add(new 
            ChangeRequest(socket, ChangeRequest.CHANGEOPS, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE));

        synchronized (this.pendingData) {
            List queue = (List) this.pendingData.get(socket);
            if (queue == null) {
                queue = new ArrayList();
                this.pendingData.put(socket, queue);
            }
            queue.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
        }
    }
    this.selector.wakeup();
}
```

And this is the relevant code they use for their run() method:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        synchronized (this.pendingChanges) {
            Iterator changes = this.pendingChanges.iterator();
            while (changes.hasNext()) {
                ChangeRequest change = (ChangeRequest) changes.next();
                switch (change.type) {
                    case ChangeRequest.CHANGEOPS:
                    SelectionKey key = change.socket.keyFor(this.selector);
                    key.interestOps(change.ops);
                }
            }
            this.pendingChanges.clear();
        }

        this.selector.select();
        ...
    }
}
```

My problem is that if a context switch occurred during the main loop, after the synchronized block but before the call to select() to someone calling the public send method, then it's possible to just hold on to the write until the next data is written or ready to be read (the selector key wouldn't be updated to write, and the selector wouldn't receive the wakeup signal).  For my purposes that would be unacceptable (if true), but I can't change functionality too much just to accommodate such a fringe corner case (like by adding a timeout to the select).  I've tried to think of a way to better synchronize the sections, or to ensure that the select is called before a context switch could occur, but I'm stuck.

EDIT:  Because of some confusion about the concurrency problem I'm going to state it more clearly here.

Run thread: Enters synchronized block with no pending changes.

Run thread: Exits synchronized block.

Scheduler: Context switches.

Other thread: Calls send method.

Other thread: Enqueues a pending change and pending data

Other thread: Calls selector.wakeup()

Scheduler: Context switches.

Run thread: Blocks on selector.select(), oblivious to the pending data.

Run thread: Continues to block forever if no one tries to use the socket again.

The reason I think this involves both NIO and multithreading is because I'm looking for a way to properly synchronize the selector.select() method.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hold onto the write'?

Comment: @EJP I mean that the data to be written will be stored in the pendingData queue, but because of the concurrency issue it won't process that data like it should.  It'll just block on the select looking for reads, oblivious to the new data.

Comment: Well you should certainly have a timeout on the select in any case, regardless of this problem, and it should be short, of the order of ten seconds. You will want to do background things like expire dead sessions if `select()` returns zero after a timeout, for example.

Comment: You don't hold on to the write.  It is a constant parameter to the ChangeRequest, implemented as an enum.  That change request was constructed in the synchronized block, and you don't have a reference to it, the pendingChanges collection does.  Protection against it being read before you leave the critical block is ensured by locking the pendingChanges collection, so even after you alter the selection key, other threads cannot race ahead and grab the actual ChangeRequest.

Comment: @EdwinBuck When I say that you hold on to the write what I mean is that if this socket were only written to one time, and the concurrency issue that I described were to occur, then that data would never be written to the socket.  After the main loop leaves the synchronized section of code, but before the subsequent select actually occurs, there's a small window where a thread could call the public send method and not get noticed by the main loop.

Comment: @EJP I'm actually writing code for a nio client that only needs to manage its one socket connection.  Other than fixing this one concurrency issue, is there any benefit to adding a timeout to select on a single socket connection?

Comment: @billie I always think you should use a finite timeout. It gives you a chance to check things, such as read timeouts, booleans that tell you to shut down, ... in any case code that can block forever will block forever sometime and puzzle you.

Comment: The ROX NIO tutorial is garbage. Guy doesn't even know that closing the channel cancels the key, and he invents a lot of non-existent difficulties about other things as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the selector wouldn't receive the wakeup signal

and

> then trying to wake up the selector (which does nothing because the selector isn't being selected on)

Untrue. See the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#wakeup--):

> If no selection operation is currently in progress then the next invocation of one of these methods will return immediately unless the `selectNow()` method is invoked in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

Being switched off the CPU doesn't mean that a lock is suddenly lost, but "regained" when you're switched back on the CPU.

Assuming that you are swapped off the CPU and another thread meant to alter "pendingChanges" somehow was given cycles before you exited the critical block, the ram associated with the lock would have to be accessed by the advancing thread, and it would then see the lock and block.

Eventually the scheduler for the CPU would notice the thread entering the blocked (waiting) state, and deprioritize it.  Sooner or later the thread holding the lock should gain enough priority to be rescheduled onto the CPU and release the lock.

In any case, only one thread will be accessing `this.pendingChanges`, and that thread will be the only one capable of mutating it.

Comment: This doesn't really address my concern, which is about if the context switch happens **after** the synchronized section of code (meaning the lock is released already) then (legally) allowing another thread to call the public send method causing the concurrency issue.

Comment: @billie This is the reason the pending changes are cleared.  Once you obtain them,  and work them, you remove them.  Of course the send is called afterwards (because without it, you could never reuse the framework).  The point is that you can't pull from the queue while it is being added to.  This is typical producer, consumer queue.  The selector wakeup makes the thread that reads come out of a sleep, if it was in one.  This line of questioning is not about NIO really, it's about believing in java synchronization in general.

Comment: Main thread enters synchronized block, sees that there are no pending changes, exits synchronized block, and a context switch occurs to thread 2.  Thread 2 finishes calling the send method, adding a value to the pending changes and pending data queues and then trying to wake up the selector (which does nothing because the selector isn't being selected on).  Then the main thread selects **indefinitely** if no one else ever tries to write to use the socket.  That data just sits in the pending data queue while we block waiting for data to be put in the pending data queue...

Comment: @billie The while loop in the lower block is "while true" or a forever loop.  If the pending changes are added before the loop registers interest in receiving the message, the message is still delivered to the loop at a later date.  This is not fire-and-forget messaging, it is queued until someone notices.

Comment: select is a blocking method call, if no activity happens on the socket until after the data from the send call is processed (like in my case) then it will block indefinitely.  A "while true" loop means nothing if there's a blocking call in that loop that never returns, which is a case I ran into and have laid out.

Comment: @billie So you want the processing loop, which does the select() to effectively spin when it has no work to do?  That's just weird, and I think nobody at ROX or in other places intended what you are suggesting.  Why would you make your main thread process read and write requests?  It is more like an event dispatch thread in Swing than a do everything thread.

Comment: What I'm talking about is exactly what they are doing in the code I linked that was written by them, and it's the purpose of select in the first place, so it's not weird at all...  The purpose of select() is to block (without spinning) to reduce cpu usage while waiting for a signal from the OS that the socket is ready for a read/write.  I'm not using it in another way than is intended, I'm just trying to find a way to make THEIR implementation thread safe.

Comment: @billie Sorry, I misread your reply the first time.  Their implementation is thread safe because there is only one thread handling all the responses across all the sockets.  NIO tends to use threads for stages in the read / process / respond network communication pattern, instead of a thread per request.  When the NIO thread pattern works, you get one thread that's always relatively close to the data it is working on, and fewer threads per machine, even when it is handling more sockets.